# How to fix pixel flaw when calling img url to mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, azure-blob-storage

I'm using azure web storage to store image files as blobs. When i call the image url of theese images to the computer they work fine. However when calling them to mobile(iOS) they sometimes get some wierd pixels and/or duplicating itself sometimes but not always. I'm putting two examples that can occur below, and as you can see one image got split in half an the other add some blue paint on it [image]

[image]

If anyone has any clue about what may be causing this, please let me know!

Edit: I've noticed that the photos that may mess up are all bigger in storage size 1MB+ while the others around 200kb seem to be doing fine, could this have something to do with it?

Comment: Have you been able to determine whether the issue is related to the data as stored - eg - if you retrieve the persisted blob multiple times from different clients it is always corrupt? Or is it to do with retrieval of the blob? More information plus repro steps would be helpful. Btw, we are working on an IOS library which might be worth looking at as well...

Answer (score 1):

I can now confirm that this was due to the actual blob size, I've made a serverside code to resize the images to below 100kb each and havent had the problem since